# GestureDetector on markers of Flutter_map isnt working

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

I'm trying to create a map using flutter_maps, but when I add a GestureDetector to the markers, some errors appear

```
          MarkerLayer(
            markers: [
              Marker(
                point: LatLng(-22.3285, -49.0523),
                width: 65,
                height: 50,
                builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    //nothing yet
                  },
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4, vertical: 2),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'BLOCOS C, D & E',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

the errors are "The named parameter 'child' is required, but there's no corresponding argument." and "The named parameter 'builder' isn't defined."

Comment: The `Marker` class does not have a `builder` parameter. You IDE should be warning you about that, as well as looking at the docs of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, heed the warning: Instead of `builder` pass a `child` to the Marker. According to the doc it does not have a parameter `builder`: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map/Marker-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
MarkerList = [ 
Marker(
    point: position,
    width: 22,
    height: 22,
    child: Tooltip(
        message: tooltipText,
        child: InkWell(
            child: SvgPicture.string(svgString),
            onTap: () => setState(() {
              // do something
            })
        )
    )
)
```

];